# Plugin-Install: postflight not executed and language-files not re-read

Tags: php, joomla, joomla3.0

I'm working on a plugin and would like to use the plugins id in some text-constants. So I thought I'll do the following: in postflight-code, find the id of the plugin and replace it in the language-files. To easily "see" it was executed, I also decided to name the language-files initially with extension "inix" and replace that with "ini" as part of postflight. But that does not happen, postflight is not executed! Why?

Also, if you care to spend some more time imvestigating, there is a problem in the handling of language-files and I do not know how to handle this: after the FIRST installation, you'll see that the text COM_FOO_PLG_DESC is shown - this constant is not replaced with its value. If you then. go and edit the zip and change the version-number in the .ini-files to 2 and install again, you will notice that this text is shown, but still refers to V1! So...the updated language-files are not re-read during installation - I believe that should happen! So I also inserted code to re-load that into postflight, but...(see above) it does not get executed.

---

The whole thing can be fetched from http://mbaas.de/plg_foo.zip 
and here are some of the essentials:

foo.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<extension type="plugin" version="1.6" method="upgrade" group="content">
<name>Content - foo</name>
<creationDate>2013-05-30</creationDate>
<version>2.0.0.16</version>
<releaseDate>2013-05-30 12:00:58</releaseDate>
<releaseType>First public release!</releaseType>
<author>Michael Baas</author>
<authorEmail>mb@mbaas.de</authorEmail>
<authorUrl>mbaas.de</authorUrl>
<copyright>(c) 2013 Michael Baas</copyright>
<description>COM_FOO_PLG_DESC</description>
<files>
<filename plugin="foo">foo.php</filename>
<folder>language</folder>
</files>
<scriptfile>foo.scriptfile.php</scriptfile>
<languages folder="language">
<language tag="en-GB">en-GB/en-GB.plg_content_foo.ini</language>
<language tag="de-DE">de-DE/de-DE.plg_content_foo.ini</language>
<language tag="en-GB">en-GB/en-GB.plg_content_foo.sys.inix</language>
<language tag="de-DE">de-DE/de-DE.plg_content_foo.sys.inix</language>
</languages>
</extension>
```

and foo.scriptfile.php:

```
    <?php
class plgContentcbmdebugInstallerScript
{
    public function __constructor(JAdapterInstance $adapter)
    {
    }
    static function loadLanguage() {
        $lang =& JFactory::getLanguage();
        $lang->load('plgContentfoo', JPATH_ADMINISTRATOR , null , true);
    }

    function preflight($type, $adapter)
    {
        echo "<b>prelight!</b>";
        $table        = JTable::getInstance('extension');
        if ($table->load(array('element' => 'foo', 'type' => 'plugin')))
        {
            $id=$table->extension_id;
            $arr = array(
            0=>"de-DE",
            1=>"en-GB"
            );
            foreach($arr as $iso) {
                $fl_lng = JPATH_ADMINISTRATOR  . "/language/$iso/$iso.plg_content_foo.sys.ini";
                unlink($fl_lng);
            }
        }
    }

    function postflight($type, $adapter)
    {
        echo "<b>postflight!</b>";
        $table        = JTable::getInstance('extension');
        if ($table->load(array('element' => 'foo', 'type' => 'plugin')))
        {
            $id=$table->extension_id;
            $arr = array(
            0=>"de-DE",
            1=>"en-GB"
            );
            foreach($arr as $iso) {
                $fl_lngx = JPATH_PLUGINS  . "/content/cbmdebug/language/$iso/$iso.plg_content_foo.sys.inix";
                $fl_lng = JPATH_ADMINISTRATOR  . "/language/$iso/$iso.plg_content_cbmdebug.sys.ini";
                $xx = file_get_contents($fl_lngx);
                $xx = str_replace("tHiS-Id",$id,$xx);
                file_put_contents($fl_lng,$xx);
                unlink($fl_lngx);
            }
            self::loadLanguage();
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As a start, the classname of your scriptfile needs to be related to the name of your plugin. That means if the plugin is a content plugin named foo, the class name has to be `plgContentFooInstallerScript`.
The classname of your scriptfile however is `plgContentcbmdebugInstallerScript`. I think you renamed the plugin to show here but missed that one. Assuming your plugin is named `cbmdebug`, the classname would still be wrong as it should be `plgContentCbmdebugInstallerScript` (note the uppercase characters).

As for the languagefile loaded. During install, only the sys.ini file is loaded. Since you don't have such a file in your package, Joomla can't load anything.

On a sidenote: Why are you even trying to manipulate the language strings? Did you try to use `JText::sprintf()` (http://api.joomla.org/Joomla-Platform/Language/JText.html#sprintf). It would allow you to pass the plugin id to the language string where it's inserted by PHP sprintf function.

Comment: Thank you - that "cbmdebug" should have been replaced with "foo" when I build the example, after doing so the code certainly is executed! :-)

The sys.ini was supposed to be created during postflight, after inserting the id. Reason for doing so was that I wanted to use that id in the description, so I can sprintf there...
Will  modify my original script now and see how things move on from there, thanks a lot for your help! :)